# Using selection stored as variable in a VBA cell formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a selected range (which is conditional based on the user input) which is stored as a variable in a VBA generated cell formula.

When using the myCells.Address value in a message box, I can see the variable is correctly storing the selected range. however, when I am trying to insert this into a cell formula created through VBA code I either get a type mismatch error (when storing as a range) or an object required error when storing as a string.

I have tried converting the stored range in myCells variable into either a string or range to be used in the .formula but neither seems to be acceptable,

```
Sub Calculate_Average()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sSheet As String
Dim Year As Range
Dim myCells As Range
Dim Repairer As Range
Dim range2 As Range

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set Year = ws.Range("$c$5:$s$5")
Set Repairer = ws.Range("$b$8:$b$52")


sSheet = InputBox( _
Prompt:="Enter current month in format mmm-yy", _
Title:="Input Month")

        If sSheet = "May-19" Then GoTo loopexit ''debug
        If sSheet = "Jun-19" Then GoTo loopexit ''debug


'' loop through cells in Year range to find matching date

For Each Cell In Year

        Cell.Select ''debug

        If ActiveCell.Value = sSheet Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, -2).Select
            Selection.Resize(Selection.Rows.Count, Selection.Columns.Count + 2).Select
            Set myCells = Selection
            MsgBox (myCells.Address)
            ws.Range("B6").Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & myCells.Address & ")"
            ActiveCell.Copy
            Repairer.Select
            PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
            GoTo loopexit
        Else
            MsgBox ("error") ''debug
        End If
Next Cell
loopexit: ''debug

End Sub
```

The formula is entered into cell b6 and should look like =average($c6:$E6) and then be copied into the range b$8:$b$53 adjusting to reflect the change in row.

Comment: Have you tried: `ws.Range("B").Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & range2.address & ")"`?

Comment: Hi, This now works thanks for this... made some slight changes see code above. Now running into the problem where the formulas are not being pasted into the repairer.range. also the selection range is locked $c$6:$e$6 rather than $c6:$E6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my problem.

Probably not the best solution but it works. Amending the formula afterwards to remove the cell locking feature. Then used a different method to copy into the cells in the repairer range.

```
Sub Calculate_Average()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sSheet As String
Dim Year As Range
Dim myCells As Range
Dim Repairer As Range
Dim range2 As Range
Dim FindRng As Range

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set Year = ws.Range("$c$5:$s$5")
Set Repairer = ws.Range("b8:b52")


sSheet = InputBox( _
Prompt:="Enter current month in format mmm-yy", _
Title:="Input Month")

        If sSheet = "May-19" Then GoTo loopexit ''debug
        If sSheet = "Jun-19" Then GoTo loopexit ''debug


'' loop through cells in Year range to find matching date

Set FindRng = Year.Find(What:=sSheet, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then ' see that find was successful
    FindRng.Select

        If ActiveCell.Value = sSheet Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, -2).Select
            Selection.Resize(Selection.Rows.Count, Selection.Columns.Count + 2).Select
            Set myCells = Selection
            MsgBox (myCells.Address)
            ws.Range("B6").Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & myCells.Address & ")"
            Range("B6").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(RC4:RC6)"
            Range("B6").Select
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B6:B52")
            Range("B6:B52").Select

            GoTo loopexit
        Else
    MsgBox "Error, unable to match", vbCritical
        End If
        End If

loopexit: ''debug

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am missing something here but you don't need to loop. You can do the formula in one go then copy and paste as values:

```
With Range("B6:B52")
    .Formula = "=average(C6:E6)" 'Excel is smart enough to increase this per row
    .Copy
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
end with
```

No selecting and no looping.